# Transparency - replace EVAL in matlab

Tags: matlab, eval, transparency, parfor

I have the following code that does some sorting on matlab, but relies on eval. This is part of a much bigger set of code, and I have simplified it to be able to put it here. Basically, I am looking for an easy way of getting rid of the function eval, so that I can use a parfor statement earlier in the code.

```
t = 1;
N = 1500;
BM = rand(N,1);
P1 = rand(N,12);
nport = 10;
tSpan            = t : t + 11;
pointer = round([1; N*.10; N*.20; N*.30; N*.40;N*.50; N*.60; N*.70; N*.80; N*.90; N]);  % pointers used in sorting
IndStru  = struct('idp1', [], 'idp2', [], 'idp3', [], 'idp4', [], 'idp5',[],'idp6', [], 'idp7', [], 'idp8', [], 'idp9', [], 'idp10',[]);


[ssize, sInd] = sort(BM);     clear ssize
ids1    = sInd(pointer(1)     : pointer(2));
ids2    = sInd(pointer(2) + 1 : pointer(3));
ids3    = sInd(pointer(3) + 1 : pointer(4));
ids4    = sInd(pointer(4) + 1 : pointer(5));
ids5    = sInd(pointer(5) + 1 : pointer(6));     
ids6    = sInd(pointer(6) + 1 : pointer(7));
ids7    = sInd(pointer(7) + 1 : pointer(8));
ids8    = sInd(pointer(8) + 1 : pointer(9));
ids9    = sInd(pointer(9) + 1 : pointer(10));
ids10    = sInd(pointer(10) + 1 : pointer(11));     clear sInd

for i = 1 : nport
            eval(['IndStru.idp' num2str(i) '=ids' num2str(i) ';' ]);
            eval(['p10(' num2str(i) ',' num2str(tSpan(1)) ':' num2str(tSpan(12)) ') = sum(P1(IndStru.idp' num2str(i) ', tSpan))']);

end
```

Comment: Your example does not work, specifically line 24, plus the missing `for`. As for the first `eval`, look at [Generate Field Names from Variables](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html), the second can just be spelled out, no need for strings.

Comment: Thanks. There was a typo when converting my code for this MWE. Now it should be fine. I will take a look to the link you posted.

Comment: Actually, I think you are going the wrong way about this? Structs with numbered fields seems strange. What are you trying to solve.

Comment: I have a vector BM, and I want to sort it into 10 parts (nport). 
Once I have done that I want to compute some stuff using P1, given the sorted 10 parts of BM. In my actual code the last line of the for loop is slightly more complex.

Comment: So the struct `IndStru` is simply for indexing?

Comment: Yes, indeed - just to let me know which entries of BM belong to each of the 10 parts.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the opportunity to try it in detail, but here is the generic answer to your problem:

You currently put an *index* in the **name** of a struct (or field?).

Rather than doing that, simply keep the names fixed and add dimensions.

So rather than using variables like `myvar1` use a `struct` like `myvar(1)`.

Once you have made this change it should be easy to access all your data without eval.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the following should be equivalent

```
t = 1;
N = 1500;
BM = rand(N,1);
P1 = rand(N,12);
nport = 10;
tSpan = t : t + 11;

[~, sInd] = sort(BM);
ids = zeros(N/nport, nport);
for i = 1:nport   
   ids(:,i) = sInd(((i-1)*N/nport +1):i*N/nport);
end

p10 = zeros(nport, 12);
for i = 1 : nport
   p10(i, tSpan) = sum(P1(ids(:,i), tSpan), 1);           
end
```

Instead of using a struct to store the indexes, I generate a matrix `ids` of indexes to use in P1.